# D3 collapsible tree with attributes

Tags: d3.js

See my code at this location:  https://codepen.io/tbellmer/pen/wvBPapB

```
enter code here
```

I have created a D3 collapsible tree and now want to place mouseover attributes into the light gray rectangle in the upper left of the display.

However, I am doing something wrong as I am unable to write "Hello!" as text into this area at line 673.  The goal is to display attributes like name, city, state, zip, phone into that light gray area as I am moused over the circle for that node.  Seems simple enough but I am struggling and looking for some assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to append a `text` node to a `rect` node. This won't work. Instead you could append both to a containing `g`

```
let infoG = svg.append('g')

let info = infoG.append('rect')
  .attr('x', -150)
  .attr('y', 10)
  .attr('width', 150)
  .attr('height', 200)
  .attr('fill', 'lightgray');

  infoG.append('text')
    .attr('x', 5)
    .attr('y', 10)
    .text('Hello!');
```